# implement event handler after other event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have on page few radio buttons and span element. When I click some radio button, Onchange event handler triggers and changes text of the span element. I dont have access to that event handler, so I can't change it.
I need to write my own script (Onchage event handler too), that will change text of the span element after other script, which described above, change the span element in DOM.
Example:
HTML:

```
<div>
<input type="radio" name="somename" value="1.232" checked="checked">1.232
<input type="radio" name="somename" value="2.556">2.556
<input type="radio" name="somename" value="3.232">3.232
<input type="radio" name="somename" value="4.865">4.865
</div>
<span id="change">1.232</span>
```

Javascript:

```
$('div input:radio').change(function(){
    //some logic here
    //calculation of value of the varaiable 'new_value' is encapsulated
    //new_value = .....
    $(#change).html(new_value);
});
```

I can't change the javascript code above.
I need to write onChange event handler to change html of the span depends on new value, which the script above maked. If I will just write:

```
$('div input:radio').change(function(){
    alert($(#change).html());
});
```

I will alert old the value of the span.
How to implement this?

Comment: Without code, we cannot help

Comment: Why can't you change the current event handler?

Comment: cause the site hosts on the cloud service

Comment: I have one solution, but it's not good. setTimeout(function(){alert($(#change).html());},1)

Comment: I'm not seeing the effect your talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/a3dAW/

Comment: How is the script that you can't change included on the page? Is it included _before_ your own script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so the problem is calling `.html()` doesn't actually trigger an event (one might expect a change event to be called in this circumstance), so you have to extend jQuery (not that hard actually) so there is something you can listen for you can try this: ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ga2zV/))

```
(function ($) {
    // create a reference to the old `.html()` function
    var htmlOriginal = $.fn.html;

    // redefine the `.html()` function to trigger an event
    $.fn.html = function (html) {
        var ret = htmlOriginal.apply(this, arguments);
        //if ret is a String then there is no event to trigger
        if(typeof ret !== "string") {
            ret.trigger('html-change');
        }
        return ret;
    }
})(jQuery);

$(function () {
    $('div input:radio').change(function () {
        var v = $(this).val();
        //Original and magical value
        setTimeout(function () {
            //Just doing some async stuff to prove that these are decoupled
            $('#change').html(v);
        }, 500);
    });

    $('#change').on('html-change', function () {
        //Now just listen to the html-change event which will be triggered any time .html() is called even that call was made by previously unmodified code)
        alert($(this).html());
    });
});
```

Comment: The problem is that it was just example. The logic of changing span value is not that simple in the scipt code, which i can't change.

Comment: Care to take another stab at adding to your question's code example so it's closer to the problem you are facing?